# MATLAB: Designing a "Warm Start"

Tags: matlab

I'm currently coding a function in MATLAB that has two steps:

1. It processes some data
2. It does some calculations on the processed data

I'm using the function to run a series of experiments, where I tweak the way calculations occur in step 2).

Seeing how I'm working with a large dataset and the data processing step takes a while each time, however, I'm wondering whether there is anyway to code in a "warm start" in the function.

That is to say, is there anyway to save all the progress that I've done after step 1) so that if I run the function a second or third time, it can skip step 1) and go right to step 2)?

EDIT: Thank you all for your suggestions. There are multiple ways of doing this - and I think that the suggestion by Kitsune works best for my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function data = get_data(varargin)
persistant stored_data
if nargin>1 && any(strcmp(varargin,'--reload'))
  stored_data=[];
end
if isempty(stored_data)
  stored_data = ...;
end

return stored_data;
```

Comment: +1: I would generally suggest breaking the entire code into two parts (i.e. initial processing and secondary processing in separate functions), but if the intent is to keep everything in one function, [persistent variables](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/persistent.html) are definitely the most straight-forward solution.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this involves writing a [class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/ug_intropage.html) instead of a function. The following defines a very basic class that you can expand as much as you want. It requires that you break up the two steps in your function into two functions called `runFirstStep` and `runSecondStep` in my example.

You'd run it as

```
obj = myAwesomeClass;
finalResults = obj.run(inputData); %# pass inputData for the first step if necessary
```

The intermediate result is stored in `obj.intermediateResults`, so if you call `run` again, the first step is automatically omitted.

If you want, you can add a set and a get function for the property `intermediateResults`. The set function would write the results to disk whenever you write to the function, and the get function would attempt to load intermediate results (if they're present) whenever it's called and the property is stil empty.

```
classdef myAwesomeClass<handle
properties
   intermediateResults
end 
methods
   function finalResults = run(obj,inputData)
        %# run accepts the object and runs both steps, if necessary
        %# inputData is the data that is processed (if it's not loaded inside runFirstStep)

        %# the first step only needs to run if there are no intermediate results
        if isempty(obj.intermediateResults)
           obj.intermediateResults = runFirstStep(inputData);
        end

        %# we always want to run the second step
        finalResults = runSecondStep(obj.intermediateResults);
    end
end
end
```

Obviously, you could also save `finalResults` in a property, add set/get methods with saving for it as well, and you could add a `plot` method that would produce nice plots of your results. In short, the class allows you to conveniently collect all the functionality required to interact with your data.

Answer (score 1):

As Jonas points out, making a class can be a solution, though there can be some subtle details if step 2 is part of the class (then you'd want to be able to modify the methods of the class).

Another common solution is to have a function do step 1 and return some data structure or collection of arrays (whatever's appropriate for your situation).  You can save these out to disk if needed.  You then pass these data items to your step 2 function or functions.

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of problem I like to separate out the two stages into two separate functions.  One generates the data, storing it as fields of a structure.  I then save this structure.  A master script runs both parts if needed.

```
function mystruct = gen_data( ... )
    mystruct.field = ...;
end
```

Which is used once, to do this:

```
mystruct = gen_data( ... );
save(mystruct, 'mystruct.mat');
```

The main processing function takes this struct as one of its arguments:

```
function result = process_data(mystruct, ...)
    % do stuff
end
```

I usually run the processing through a master script.  I also keep my workspaces and saved variables in version control in parallel with my code and history, so I can work backwards to what it was that made a particular result.

```
if (~exist('mystruct'))
    load('mystruct.mat');
end
result = process_data(mystruct);
```